# Text overwrite in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Really silly problem here.

In Visual Studio 2010, the text cursor has changed from the blinking line, to a blinking grey box around the characters. When I type overwrites the text in front of it.

I'm not sure how to get this off? It's like what happens when you press the insert key in microsoft word and overwrite mode gets turned on.

I'm working on a mac with a windows virtual machine so when I hit insert it's just a shortcut key for Parallels (the Virtual Machine program I'm running).

Would appreciate any help!!

Comment: I assume you have tried hitting the Insert key again?

Comment: Of course I have :P I'm working on a mac with a windows virtual machine so when I hit insert it's just a shortcut key for Parallels (the Virtual Machine program I'm running). I thought there might be a setting somewhere in the options menu I could change.

Comment: If the Microsoft folks ever read this one, this is one of those features that deserves to go the way of CTRL-ALT-DELETE. There are probably a few users who like it. But as the votes on this question show, for the vast majority, it's like a trap that you can enable by accident, and then you have to search for how you can get rid of it.

Comment: If the option is on and the user toggles insert X number of times in Y seconds/minutes, there should be some kind of a tooltip that pops up alerting of the setting.

Answer (score 323, accepted):

If pressing the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key doesn't work, try doubleclicking the INS/OVR label in the lower right corner of Visual Studio.

Comment: thanks bAN, I don't even have an insert on my keyboard so not sure how it happened to me ;) can confirm the click trick works in VS 2012, but it is INS/OVR

Comment: This of course reminds me of the "is it a bug or feature" issue. I would call it a usability bug. First, I would never use that button. Second, today I somehow must have hit that button inadvertently, and was stumbled, like the Original Poster, to find that the Ins keyboard button was not working. To end on a positive note, how about "connecting" those two buttons in the next version of VS, Microsoft?

Comment: not sure how I got into this mode, but not insert key on my macbook, and this solved it.

Comment: A screenshot would make this answer even better.

Comment: its disabled in vs 2019. it automatically enables to me without any reason.

Answer (score 26):

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Win 8.1. It was Shift + 0 (0 is my insert key) on the number pad of my laptop.

Comment: Life saver! For some reason double clicking OVR wasn't doing the trick, Shift+0 must be how I got here in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: I've got an iMac running windows on Virtual Box, my keyboard has numeric pad... I think I would never find the correct button, thank you!

Comment: Yeh, Life saver! 
worked on a disktop Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019. Don't forget to unlock the number pad ;).

Comment: NumLock should be on!

Answer (score 14):

None of the solutions above were working for me. My workaround was to open the on-screen keyboard using the system settings (press Windows key and search for "keyboard" to find them). Once that's open you can click the Insert key on it.

Comment: Thanks - that was the key for me. I was using a keyboard with no "insert" key through remote desktop to another computer and somehow triggered the insert key.

Comment: i was facing same issue i have no "Insert" key option in my laptop Windows key and search for "keyboard" to find them). Once that's open you can click the "Insert" key on it.solve my problems

Comment: this is much helpful than the other answers here

Comment: It appears my keyboard special keys stopped working (had to reboot it as it is a mechanical with internal drive and programming).  The on-screen keyboard was the fastest/best fix to get around this without dinking with my keyboard at the moment.  My VS Enterprise 2019, up to date on version, is not allowing me to use the bottom right 'over' label as a toggle.

Comment: I'm using windows on mac using bootcamp, I don't have an insert key and none of the solutions above worked, this solved It for me though, thanks

Answer (score 13):

I'm using Visual Studio with Parallels/Win 7 on a MacBook laptop keyboard and the only thing that worked was <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd> (that's the Mac shortcut for Insert).

Comment: Question clearly states that the person was working on a Mac... must be on a Windows keyboard. This was what I was looking for!

Comment: This tip saved my life.  Was going nuts.  Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Ran into this issue with Parallels and VS 2013. Command + Insert also fixed it in my setup, in addition to the accepted answer. On my Windows USB keyboard Command == WindowsKey.

Comment: I can also add that this trick works when running Citrix Viewer on a Mac! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

**Visual Studio** : 
**Right Bottom** : Look for **OVR** label.
**Double Click** on it.

Bingo...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have an insert key, and you're using Visual Studio 2019, then double-clicking the OVR text in the bottom right corner does not work.  You'll have to use an on-screen keyboard, if you have one of those, or figure out what your insert key is mapped to.  For me, on my mac keyboard hooked up to windows 10, it is the 0 key on the keypad.

Comment: Legend, the other things weren't working but you helped a ton tnx!

Answer (score 2):

press your keyboard ***Insert*** Key

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I used the shortcut below:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

**there is 2 ways to disable this option :**

- the first one is to go :
  Visual Studio, Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, remove the shortcut binding for `Edit.OvertypeMode`
- the other way to disable it is to use **AutoHotKey** or any other Key-Overwriting App

but i strongly recommend **AutoHotKey** because it allow you to specify what application you want the key to be disabled in, and keep the same key work when ***VS studio window*** is minimized or closed .

AutoHotKey also uses scripting language , thats the best part, so you have a large flexibility to do many things that other generic key-overwriting apps can-not do

1- after installing **AutoHotKey** create a new file ends with **.ahk**

2- type inside it the following script :

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe devenv.exe   ; <<== perform only when visual studio Window is Active
Insert::Return                    ; <<== Force Empty return on (**Insert**) key
#IfWinActive                      ; <<== end of #If statement
```

3- save the file , double click to run . 
that's it ! . 
go inside VS studio now and try to press Insert key ,
 it wont work anymore unless you disable that script we just created .

> **Note :** the Script need to be open everytime you open Visual Studio , so you could make the script start with windows , just put it inside the folder **"AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"**

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this happens to you on Mac: <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just saved my python file and exited Visual Studio. Reloaded file and setting were restored.

Answer (score 0):

This error is really annoying. I'm using VS code on Mac and the cursor is not default insert mode when I open the files.

**INS/OVR** label also didn't find.

Try to customize some settings/configs also didn't work.

Finally I can solve this issue by uninstalling **vim** extension from my vs-code.

Don't forget to restart vs-code after uninstalling **vim**.