# Visual Studio 2010 cursor problems

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, cursor

I am using C#.NET in Visual Studio 2010 (on Windows 7) and am having trouble with what seems to be a cursor setting.  When I open Visual Studio, the cursor seems to be set to "read" mode, is the width of a text character, and typing does not change the code.  I can set it to "insert" mode (the thin cursor) when I press "insert", but highlighting text changes it back.  I also can't delete highlighted text with "backspace".  How can I fix this so the cursor is always in "insert" mode and highlighted text is deleted with the "backspace" key?  I've tried looking elsewhere online and cannot figure this out, and it's making it much harder for me to code.

Apparently, it is not the same solution as the one here: [Text overwrite in visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089876/text-overwrite-in-visual-studio-2010).  Unlike the person who posted that question, I don't have a virtual machine atop my basic OS.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Do you have any Visual Studio plugins that might be doing this, or is this a clean install of Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't think there are plugins.  All of a sudden, I pressed something and this cursor issue began.

Comment: Some googling shows that VS can go "read-only" when source control is involved.  Any chance that's related?

Comment: what site are you looking at?

Comment: various results from this query: https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+cursor+mode

Comment: I performed that search.  The answers here don't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089876/text-overwrite-in-visual-studio-2010