# What is block cursor in VS Code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

What does the block cursor mean in Visual Studio Code and how do I get out of it?

I'm not able to do carriage returns.

[image]

Comment: Insert key? Where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text overwrite in visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089876/text-overwrite-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: @the4kman: Nope.

Comment: I had the same problem - it was an extension I'd installed in Visual Code, a VIM extension.  I uninstalled the extension, and was able to get back to work...  HTH someone.

Answer (score 1):

Under the code menu go to preferences/settings. This opens the default setting for vsCode. You can change these using the screen on the right. Search for "block" using search line near top. Using left window, paste line that defines block and change "block" to "line".

Comment: there is also another curser for the terminal window. that is probably block too. you might try changing that one.