# visual studio mouse clicking white thing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

only starting with programming on C#, and idk why, but when i click, i get a like a block selected, it is so hard to explain, so ill left here a screenshot. Does someone know, how can i change this to a normal click?

[image]

I tryed to search up this in internet, but i cant normally explain, and i could find it in setting too.

Comment: As suggested by mozart, just hit the INSERT key on your keyboard. This will toggle the mode of your cursor between "insert" and "overwrite" modes. The solid block is overwrite mode. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089876/text-overwrite-in-visual-studio-2010) for some other options...

Comment: There's an `insert` key on your keyboard, that's it. If the answer below solves your problem, you can mark it so others with the same problem can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your case, it is quite hard to help if the question is too short.

I guess, you not deliberate to press the **Insert** button at the keyboard, and transform it like this:

[image: Screenshot.png]